How to Run pgAgent in a Separate Docker Container?
I want to run pgAgent jobs separate docker container from the database. I want to run the schedule to snapshot the data in database.

Deploy pgAgent
Configure pgAgent Container
Start the pgAgent Container
Create the pgAgent Extension in PostgreSQL

